# RPI-Clone an SSD to an SSD - Fails with I/O Error

Tags: usb, pi-4

I have a RPi 4 system with 4GB RAM and another 4GB with ZRAM.

It is running XFCE and I've successfully converted from SD to SSD. Everything works fine here as of right now.

Recently I've attempted to Clone the Boot/Root SSD to another SSD, but it doesn't seem like the Raspberry Pi can handle this very well.

I am doing the clone by using rpi-clone and executing `rpi-clone sda -v -f -L SSD-RPi` as root.

The rsync copy works fine up to a certain point, where the transfer just fails due to an input/output error.

```
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/mnt/clone/var" failed: Input/output error (5)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
var/

sent 429,998,130 bytes  received 319,856 bytes  2,006,144.46 bytes/sec
total size is 4,348,546,020  speedup is 10.11
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]

mkdir: cannot create directory ?/mnt/clone/boot?: Input/output error
  Mounting /dev/sda1 on /mnt/clone/boot
mount: /mnt/clone/boot: can't read superblock on /dev/sda1.
    Mount failure of /dev/sda1 on /mnt/clone/boot.
  unmounting /mnt/clone
Aborting!
```

The mounting of the new SSD also fails at that point.

To me it seems like the raspberry Pi USB-Bus can't handle this clone.

But I still wonder, is this in any way possible? Can I establish a more reliable cloning-process on the Raspberry Pi?

My goal would be to clone the ssd, so I can switch over without reconfiguring the whole system.

The components I use:

- Crucial BX500 240GB CT240BX500SSD1 (= Current SSD that is being cloned from aka. root)
- Corsair Force Series MP510 240GB (= Destination SSD)
- [DeLock SATA to USB Adapter](https://www.delock.de/produkt/61883/merkmale.html) (= USB-Adapter for Current SSD aka. root)
- [ICY BOX IB-1816M-C31](https://www.raidsonic.de/de/standards/searchresults.php?we_objectID=5570)
- Original Raspberry Pi 4 Power Adapter

I suspect that the components also might not be optimal for this.

So yea..

I feel like I have to do the "Turn SD to SSD"-Process again with the new SSD again. Which would be somewhat painful, thus I wanted to figure out if there were options to do a reliable "copy" on the Raspberry Pi itself with everything connected.

**UPDATE** with info from a comment:
Both are powered by the PI USB ports. It's not the most optimal setup there is.. I could try with a powered USB Hub. Also yes, I have rights to that directory. The error points that say the files are "locked" are due to the failure of the drive at that point. Meaning the files aren't accessible anymore because of a disconnection of the drive.

Comment: Do you have rights to that directory?  Error 5 points to file locks, duff disk OR security errors...

Comment: Please clarify: are both SSDs powered by the PI USB ports?

Comment: Yes, both are powered by the PI USB ports. It's not the most optimal setup there is.. I could try with a powered USB Hub.
Also yes, I have rights to that directory. The error points that say the files are "locked" are due to the failure of the drive at that point. Meaning the files aren't accessible anymore because of a disconnection of the drive.

Comment: @HackXIt   You may be running into the 1.2 A current limit (shared between all USB ports). Two external SSDs may well draw enough current to exceed this. SSDs have low average current draw, but higher peak than spinning hard drives, maybe over 1 A, so if you have two at once on the Pi you are risking trouble.

Comment: Some SSDs can hit 5 to 10 Watts peak which is 1 to 2 Amps at 5 volts.

Comment: The rpi-clone succeeded upon using a USB powered HUB, nevertheless, the information regarding the current limit is something I was unaware of and I didn't think that an SSD can draw that much power.